# Side bar fixed to left of the screen and Middle content with Margin: 0 auto

Tags: html, css

I have some different structure in my project.
I am not sure it is possible or not.

[Here is code what I have done so far.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kJjHw)

It works good for my 19 inch screen.

This is how it look on laptop screen (Sidebar overlaps the middle content)
http://s29.postimg.org/a3vfj59kn/screen2.png

My expected result is sidebar should now overlap on middle content for small screen(at least till 14 inch).

As the middle content has auto margin it leaves space form both side making sidebar overlap on it.

I could have done this using media query, however I need to support IE8 too.

I need to support at least 14 inch screen.

Its not mobile compatible site.

I would like to have only HTML/CSS solution. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar structure for one of my project in admin end.

What you can do is add wrapper div with `overflow: hidden.`

And have one more div inside wrapper div with `min-width` of as below

`middle content + (2 * with of side bar)` in your case it will be `min-width:1127px`

This will keep you middle content in center and not allow your side bar to overlap the middle content.

```css
* {
  margin: 0
}

.outer {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.innerWrap {
  min-width: 1127px
}

.leftBar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 234px;
  background: red;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.midCnt {
  width: 660px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 600px;
  background: yellow
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="innerWrap">
    <div class="leftBar">
      Sidebar
    </div>
    <div class="midCnt">
      <ul>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
        <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
        <li>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```